# How do I put multiple list levels on the same line in MS Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, list

I have a list:

```
1)

     (a)
     (b)
```

I want to format it to look like this:

```
1)   (a)
     (b)
```

How do I achieve this in MS Word 2010?

Comment: @CharlieRB I have, I'm currently trying to make something work with ListNum fields, but it's not working out so well. I intentionally left the question pretty simple. I feel like there should be a simple solution and didn't want to complicate things by talking about everything I've tried that *doesn't* work.

Comment: That makes sense, but that is how this site works. We want to know what you have tried so we can offer solutions and get the repeated "tried it" at each suggestion. It is also nice to know you have put some effort into this rather than expecting us to do it all for you. In a nut shell, more detail is better.

Comment: @CharlieRB In my mind answers should be solutions, not suggestions. Either the solution works or it doesn't. In theory, if it works for one person, it should work for everyone.

Comment: No worries. I didn't make the guidelines or the site. Just informing you what is in the [help]. If you choose not to follow the guidelines, so be it. It could be why you haven't any answers besides your own.

Answer (score 1):

I can't get the alignment to look the same as your example (assuming you do not used fixed width fonts in your documents), but there is a more automated way of doing the numbering using a list style.

[image: Example of list numbering]

1. From the styles pane, click the New Style button (micro button bottom left).
2. Select List as the Style Type and give this style a name.
3. On the Format dropdown on the lower left of this window, select Numbering. I only defined two levels for this example, but the basics are covered.

[image: Example list numbering definition]

Answer (score 0):

One solution I've come up with–though not the ideal solution, more like a cheap work-around–is to manually input the first list number of your nested list and format it to look like your list numbers, then use SHIFT+ENTER to put a hard break in your first line, and use tabs to adjust the other lines in that list item.

```
1) (a) List item stuff all the way to the margin where the line naturally
       [SHIFT+ENTER, SPACE, TAB] 
       breaks. Rest of line lines up with first like a good list item should. 
       [SHIFT+ENTER, SPACE, TAB]<-(need to do this for every line)
       Everything in this item is actually part of list item "1)". 
   (a) First item in actual nested list. You'll then need to adjust the first 
       nested list number to be list item 2. 

2) Lorem ipsum dolor sit met...
   (b) <- After you adjust your first list number in your nested list, the rest
       of your nested lists will also start with list item 2. You may have to reset 
       it to list item 1 again.
```

I'm hoping someone smarter than me can come up with a less laborious solution, but for now this works for my purposes.